# get styles of selection range in javascript

Tags: javascript, selection

All knows, that we can get selection of text in javascript by method

```
var range = window.getSelection ();
```

But, how to get style of this selection? 
When I select **bolded** text or *italic*, how to i can know about this?

(I have only one idea: get position of this selected text and get html for this position...)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `document.queryCommandState()` for things like **bold** and *italic* and `document.queryCommandValue()` for things like font size and style.

You must supply the flag to each method for it to give you a true or false value, it wont just return the current styles. So if you want to know if the selected text is bold you can write...

```
if(document.queryCommandState('Bold')){
  // its bold!
}
```

This lists the variety of identifiers and methods

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of [`document.queryCommandState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see also [dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/ljkxwclp.php)) for commands such as "Bold" and "Italic" that have no value and [`document.queryCommandValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see also [dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/ljqhsrpe.php)) for commands that have a value, such as "FontName".