# RichText editor button state on insertion point location

Tags: javascript, editor, designmode

I've created a mini browser RichText editor that implements basic stuff like bold, italic, underline, indent among others. Say I have these on my `textarea` (which is really an `iframe`):

This is a **bold** text.

and let's take the BOLD button to further describe my problem. When the insertion point is at this state: 
Thi|s is a **bold** text.

then the BOLD button would be on its normal state. However, if it is in this state:
This is a **bol|d** text

then the BOLD button would be on a selected/active state. How will I know if the BOLD button should be on an active/selected state or if it should be on a normal state with respect to the location of the insertion point?

Comment: See this question:[How to get Cursor position in Textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea)

Comment: Hi thanks @Colin. I did not want to go thru the codes of TinyMCE to satisfy my preference for the UI/UX/design. It would just be a simple editor so I wouldn't be using the other lines of codes of TinyMCE; ergo less loading time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the bold command, you can use `document.queryCommandState("bold")`.

Here's a more detailed answer to a similar question from a couple of days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8298215/96100